# How to set date and time as a default value in angularjs form field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

Hi i am newbie to angularjs, I am developing registration form. in my form i have created_At field. But this field should be filled automatically with current date and time in format("2015-02-26T07:28:01.596Z").

i am able to get the date and time as but i am not getting how to set this value into form field.

am getting date as
[image]

here i am getting value below the field, but i want to set that  time and date as createdAt field value..

here is my form  code

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
        <div   class="form-group">
            <label for="user_createdAt" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ 'user.createdAt' | translate }}</label>
            <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl"  class="col-sm-10">
                <input  type="datetime-local"  id="user_createdAt"  ng-model="user.createdAt" name="createdAt" class="form-control"  value= "{{ date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" />
            </br>{{ date }}
            <br/>{{ date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

can anyone help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: use `ng-init="user.createdAt= new Date()"` on view

Comment: @pankajparkar thanks for replay. dfsq given the solution down ,it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the corresponding `ngModel` to date object and Angular will populate input field properly, just remove `value` attribute. For example:

```
$scope.user.createdAt = new Date();
```